# Google Firestore Querying Document in a Collection inside Document

Tags: swift3, nested, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

My data is formatted as follows:

A collection of Documents C

```
----Document A

-------Date Field

-------Collection 

-----------User Document

----Document B

...
```

How would I be able to query the database for all documents in c based on the dat field in each document AND if in each respective document a certain user is in their collection field using swift